# Angular2 cli sha1 library

Tags: angular, angular-cli

how to add any known sha1 library to angular-cli project ?

I'm trying:

```
npm install crypto-js
```

then

```
typings install dt~crypto-js --global --save
```

but I don't know how to import it  later in the component

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as CryptoJS from '../../../node_modules/crypto-js';
```

write in component and use it

https://github.com/Uisli21/SecureAngularLogin might help you